# Randomly sleeting rows based on all groups in two columns

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sample

I have a large dataset with about 167k rows. I would like to take a sample of 2000 rows of it while making sure I am taking rows from all groups in two columns `(id & quality)`  in the data.
This is a snapshot of the data

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2),
                 quality=c("a","b","c","d","z","g","t"))

df %>% glimpse()
Rows: 7
Columns: 2
$ id      <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2
$ quality <chr> "a", "b", "c", "d", "z", "g", "t"
```

So, I need to ensure that the sampled data has rows from all combinations of these two group columns.
I hope someone can help out.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if the number of combinations of id & quality is greater than 2000?

Comment: Can you pick an answer, so we can close this question?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's what you're looking for.

```
my_df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                    quality = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "z", "g", "t", "t", "t"))

my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(id, quality) %>% mutate(Unique = cur_group_id())
my_df$Test <- seq.int(from = 1, to = nrow(my_df), by = 1)

my_a <- my_df %>% group_by(Unique) %>% sample_n(., 1)
my_b <- my_df %>% group_by(Unique) %>% sample_n(., 1)
my_c <- my_df %>% group_by(Unique) %>% sample_n(., 1)
my_d <- my_df %>% group_by(Unique) %>% sample_n(., 1)
my_e <- my_df %>% group_by(Unique) %>% sample_n(., 1)
```

You don't need that much dataframe, those are just examples to show that for each unique group 1 row will be extract randomly. The difference is seen in the column named "Test" especially for the id = 2 and quality = t, based on the data sample.

Comment: I can't take this approach as I have so many groups in each column and need one aggregated sample data at the end.

Comment: What do you mean you have many groups in each column ? can you provide an example of your data then with the expected result ? Because I believe for now based on your description my soluiton works.

Comment: You just said you can't take this approach but the other answer has the same approach to it, I just added a Unique column besides that the thought process is the same... But as long as you can find help for your problem I don't mind

Comment: Our approach does the same, but with different `syntax` :-) Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that each `id` and `quality` is represented in your new sample, you will need to `group` you data by these variables.

What you are looking for is the following,

```
df %>% 
        group_by(id,quality) %>% 
        sample_n(1, replace = TRUE)
```

You can change sample size pr `group` and `id`, and set `replacement` as desired.

It gives the following output,

```
# Groups:   id, quality [7]
     id quality
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 a      
2     1 g      
3     2 b      
4     2 t      
5     3 c      
6     4 d      
7     5 z
```

The data that you provided, have unique groups, and therefore sampling the way you want it, gives the same number of rows as you data.

---

**Edit:** `sample_n` is superseeded by `slice_sample`, I wasnt aware of this. But you can easily change the `script` by,

```
df %>% 
        group_by(id,quality) %>% 
        slice_sample(
                n = 1
        )
```

You can also sample a `proportion` of your `data.frame` by setting `prop` instead of `n`,

```
df %>% 
        group_by(id,quality) %>% 
        slice_sample(
                prop = 0.25
        )
```

Comment: thanks!, I need 2000 rows in total, also your method is selecting two random rows from each combination of the columns. I may not even have two rows in each combination of the two groups

Comment: Ok, if your need 2000 rows, you'll need to count the amount of `unique` `id`s, and set sample size accordingly.

If you don't have "enough", you can sample with replacement. Which I assume is your goal anyways?

Comment: I don't have to select an equal number from each combination of groups in two columns. so, replacement is not needed. `id` has 12 unique levels but I don't know how it can help.

Comment: And how many unique `quality`? It would be wiser to run `df %>% group_by(id, quality) %>% summarise(obs = n())`, and than calculate how many you would need for sample of 20.000!

Comment: Sorry, meant 2000.

Comment: For each `id` I have about 25 unique `quality`.  And not all combinations of these two columns have a same number of rows. That's why I am confused.

Comment: Start by setting `n=1` in `slice_sample`. This is the lowest point of the sample size possible, and work you way up, and see if you can reach ~2000